# TCP vs UDP for real-time chat recommendation-engine?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, real-time, recommendation-engine

I am building a chat application, where each keystroke presses of the user are sent to the server. At the server, a recommendation engine which is based on nlp generates recommendations based on the context of the typed message at that point of time.

For large scale deployment, which connection type would be preferable between TCP and UDP. UDP is fast but unreliable, whereas TCP, being reliable may be slow in real-time. For example:A user types the words "Hey, lets watch" and quickly clears the text-box,the recommendation of a movie should not be generated after he clears the text-box.

If the server has a recommendation, it should be guaranteed to deliver the recommendation back to the client.

The aim is to get real-time recommendation with low latency. Which type would be more preferable?

Comment: When it come to interacting with a human typist/reader, the difference in latency is a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

TCP and UDP are almost identical if the size of the data being sent at a time is less than the maximum payload of a single frame.

In that case UDP will be more "reliable" in terms of real-time behaviour since it is more within your hands how the data is processed. The downside of course is that you have to care of certain things yourself which TCP will give you for free.

With TCP on the other hand the TCP layer of the protocol stack can make a mess out of your real-time requirements and you don't even have a chance doing anything about it. Ever thought about re-transmitts (about +200ms transmittion time), nagle algorithm (small packets are delayed for up to 200ms), delayed TCP ACKs (may cause re-transmitts on some stacks)? And there is a lot more in stock for you if you have strickt real-tme requirements.

I'm working on a project which has a 20ms timeframe and transmitts a lot of data in that time using TCP. Even though we have a star architecture and real-time operating systems it is a hell to get this working reliable (well lots of the effects are due to one of our used Ethernet chips the smsc91c111).

Concluding there is no "best way" doing things like that since neither UDP nor TCP are real-time protocols. But since it is fairly easy to switch between them I recommend simply to test it and choose the protocol which works best.

Comment: No user will notice 20 ms latency in a chat application.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes that's true but 200ms are noticeable. The 20ms is just an example and a chat application will not have such strict real-time requirements as I have in my project.

Comment: Realtime VoIP is fine until over 250 ms. I just can't see that someone could type a message, wait for a reply, and notice that the network delayed the reply 200 ms when it will take much longer than that for the other party to read then type a single letter.

Comment: @RonMaupin That's also true. It all depends on the requirements which are unclear in the context of the question which is simply about which protocol is to be preferred. The question says "each keystroke presses of the user are sent to the server" ... if you press a key and your key shows up 200ms later it is definitely noticeable. Also we don't know how the architecture or data flow of the final application will be. And all I say is that TCP has a lot of features which are good but concerning real-time behaviour are not neccessarily to be preferred or have at least to be considered carefully.

Comment: That would be true, _if_ each and every key stroke must be acknowledged before the next one can be sent, but that is unlikely; TCP doesn't require a one-to-one ACK. More likely is why VoIP can tolerate such delays is that the first key can be sent with a 200 ms delay, and the next one is sent before the first keystroke arrives. The key strokes arrive in the same amount of time it takes to type them, but with an initial delay. Individually sent keystrokes show up on the other end with the same delay between keystrokes as the type took.

Comment: @RonMaupin As I've said we don't know enough about what the application will do. We're assuming a lot here (what if you have a requirement to transmit each char within 10ms?). I am providing some information due to my experience. How much they apply to the question is up for the questioner. And one final word: Some TCP/IP stacks require a one-to-one TCP-ACK to run in a controlled real-time fashion (back to the 20ms of my example). Well it's true that all of this most likely does not apply for chat applications but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable knowledge. To add a little more insight to the context of the question, the workflow is as follows-the user starts typing in the chat box. Each key presses(or words) are sent to the server. The server receives the typed message till at that point of time, processes it using Natural Language Processing, and returns a recommendation/suggestion if available.

Comment: For example, you start typing "hey", the string "hey" is sent to server and processed.If you continue typing say "Hey, how " the whole string goes to the server and get processed. Then you continue in this fashion until your sentence makes some sense like "Hey, how about a show at", the recommendation pops up. This should make things a bit clearer.